# Adding multiple firebase projects to one flutter(android portion) project

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

Up until now I have been working only with one firebase database, which was the test database. Now I wish to add another one, a production database, to my flutter project(the android part). When I try to register the android part of the app to the production database, this is what I get.
[image]

If I understand correctly, a package name with the same sha1 fingerprint can't be added to multiple firebase projects, and somewhere I read that the sha1 fingerprint is connected to your computer, so basically you can't change that, and I suppose the package name must be the same as it is in Android Studio.

Any ideas how to add the same project to another(production) firebase database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add multiple database into one project in [Blaze Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). So a tricky solution, handle the data in two nodes

1. Production Node
2. Testing Node

Inside your app code, get the reference accordingly.

You can find the following section in mentioned link
[image]

**Note:** this approach might exceeds your free quota, and after changing your plan to Blaze, you can create multiple databases in one project, but still you will not be able to create new project with the same package name.